# jQuery load more content when Scroll at bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, scroll

jQuery load more content when scroll to bottom of the page. My script is working well on Safari/iPad  browser and android Mozilla browser. But not worked on Android default and Chrome browsers.

```
$("#div").scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= ($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).outerHeight())) {
        // load more  content function            
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#div").animate({scrollTop: $("#div")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
    $('#div').scroll(function() {
    //content goes here
     });
```

Comment: Sorry this is for scroll top,please change scrollTop portion as per your requirement.